# Object is null using SqlCommand stored procedure to Object

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

I am trying to execute a SQL stored procedure and collect the results in a `List<T>`. I do not get errors, but the list is always null. The stored procedure produces over 100 records so I know that it should not be null, but I cannot figure out why it is null.

Here is my code:

```
List<TicketExtendedFieldModel> list = new List<TicketExtendedFieldModel>();

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetExtendedFields", con))
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    list = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as List<TicketExtendedFieldModel>;
    con.Close();
}
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` will always return a single value, never a list. You should only use `as` when you are either _sure_ that the variable is of that type or if you handle cases where it's not (in which case it will be `null`).

Answer (score 0):

Your list is null because the `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` it's not of type `List<TicketExtendedFieldModel>` . Change `ExecuteScalar` with `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: Changing ExecuteScalar to ExecuteReader does not work.  It is an immediate error.  I'm pretty sure I have to use a  SqlDataReader for that and then a While(reader.Read) which I tried to do first, but got an error trying to read field by field into the object.

Comment: Yeah, using SqlDataReader should do the trick. What error? Post the code and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8) which executes the query, and returns the **first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query**. Additional columns or rows are **ignored**.

So now how we will get the list of 100 records returned by StoredProcedure?

You can use `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` *[There are more ways to do this]*:

```
List<TicketExtendedFieldModel> list = new List<TicketExtendedFieldModel>();

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetExtendedFields", con))
{
   con.Open();
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while (rdr.Read())
   {
      TicketExtendedFieldModel obj = new TicketExtendedFieldModel();
      // your properties from TicketExtendedFieldModel and then
      // obj.name = Convert.ToString(rdr["name"]);
      list.Add(obj);
   }
   con.Close();
}
```